# Wordpress Visual composer CSS issue?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, visual-editor

I have installed visual composer successfully.  I inserted a row and divided it in `1/2 + 1/2` layout (i.e in two columns).  After inserting data in both columns  when I then inspect it, it takes single column as a whole row.

How to solve this so it looks like I require?

Here is Screen Shot [image]

My requirement is that `our values`  and `our approach` become inline to each  other as both are in a same row.

I am a new to WordPress and doing my first project.  Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you share screen shot of issue?

Comment: @ Helping Hands i have update my question please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is used by visual composer as CSS framework. As per your screenshot attached, i think that either the bootstrap CSS in you theme is not supported or may be there is a conflict with bootstrap CSS, theme and visual composer. For more detailed assistance, please provide site url.